# Как инжектить презентер @InjectPresenter ( Moxy ) во фрагмент?

Tags: moxy

У меня navigation_graph в котором крутятся фрагменты, использую Moxy.
В домашнем для navigation_graph фрагменте код:

```
class HeroListFragment: Fragment(), HeroListView{

@InjectPresenter
lateinit var heroListPresenter: HeroListPresenter
private lateinit var mAdapter: HeroAdapter

override fun onCreateView(...

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    setupAdapter()
    heroListPresenter.fetchHeroes()
}
```

тут ошибка инициализации heroListPresenter вылазит:
  lateinit property heroListPresenter has not been initialized

Хотя в активити норм работает...

Презентер:

```
@InjectViewState
```

class HeroListPresenter: MvpPresenter() {

```
fun fetchHeroes(){

    viewState.showLoading()

    val handler = Handler()

    thread {

        Thread.sleep(3000)

        val mockdata = ArrayList<Hero>()
        mockdata.add(Hero(0, "One", "", 0))
        mockdata.add(Hero(1, "Two", "", 1))
        mockdata.add(Hero(2, "Three", "", 1))

        handler.post{
            viewState.showHeroes(mockdata)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать при наследовании в вашем презентере наследуемое view

```
@InjectViewState
public class FragmentPresenter extends MvpPresenter<FragmentView>
```